# Unable to build Angular project with ngx-doc-viewer

Tags: angular, documentviewer

Its working fine when i do ng serve and normal ng build.
But when i try to build project as **ng build --prod** its throwing me error as below

**ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:77:21)
    at visitNodes (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16514:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16740:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16635:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16703:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16692:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (C:\Users\vicky\Documents\RND-Project\Angular\docPreview\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16599:21)**

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the owner of the library [here](https://github.com/Marcelh1983/angular-document-viewer/issues/20)

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

solves the problem.

Comment: It's working now with this command also 

"ng build --prod"

Thank you so much for your comment:- )

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend it as a permanent solution, but can you try building like this :

`ng build --prod --aot false --build-optimizer false`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It's working now.
It not permanent solution. Still looking for permanent solution with AOT and build-optimizer.

Comment: @VickyPal my answer below has the permanent solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59768434/554701